# Exibição dinâmica de campos obrigatórios, opcionais ou inexistentes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, reflexão

Existe uma classe que possui 12 propriedades, que em sua inserção no banco de dados podem ser obrigatórias, opcionais ou inexistentes, dependendo da regra de negócio especificada no cadastro de uma outra classe.

Como eu conseguiria elaborar uma `View` que exiba apenas os campos obrigatórios e opcionais?

Pensei em utilizar `reflection`, tendo uma lista de campos com nomes idênticos a propriedade, varrendo estes campos na `View`. Haveria alguma outra forma de se implementar esta situação?

Comment: Como você está marcando seus campos opcionais?

Comment: Para este caso específico, não estou marcando ainda os campos opcionais e obrigatórios. Pensei em criar uma classe Campos que informaria quais das 12 propriedades são obrigatórias, e qual são opcionais.

Comment: Vou postar uma resposta. Vamos ver se vai ser útil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No seu *Model* implemente a Interface `IValidatableObject`.

```
public class MyModel : IValidatableObject

public int Propriedade1 { get; set; }
public int Propriedade2 { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
   if(Propriedade1 <= 0)
        yield return new ValidationResult("Propriedade menor ou igual a 0", new List<string> { "Propriedade1" } ); //Um yield return para cada validação.
}
```

O resultado do Validate será exibido pelo jQueryValidator, usando o `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`;

Comment: Para verificar o seu método no server side é só chamar na controller:  ModelState.IsValid

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra solução seria criar uma ViewModel com os atributos que devem ou não ser escritos:

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModels {
    public class MyViewModel {
        public int Prop1 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Prop2 { get; set; }
        public String Prop3 { get; set; }
        public String Prop4 { get; set; }
        ...
        public String Prop12 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Sua View recebe, ao invés do Model em si, o ViewModel preenchido:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.MyViewModel
...
```

Seu Controller recebe o ViewModel na requisição POST e preenche um ViewModel na GET:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        return View(viewModel);
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Cities/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var model = new Model {
                Prop1 = viewModel.Prop1, 
                Prop2 = viewModel.Prop2, 
                Prop3 = viewModel.Prop3, 
                ...
                Prop12 = viewModel.Prop12
            };

            context.Models.Add(model);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, marque no seu modelo quais propriedades são obrigatórias usando o *Attribute* `[Required]`:

```
public class MyModel {
    [Key]
    public int MyModelId {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public String Description {get;set;}
}
```

Dentro da View, você pode usar o seguinte código:

```
@foreach (var propertyInfo in Model.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy))
{
    var requiredAttribute = (RequiredAttribute)propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();
    if (requiredAttribute != null)
    {
        /* Escreva um campo para a property */
    }
}
```

Comment: Este código retorna os atributos marcados como required em um model, pelo que entendi. Isto me ajuda na view, mas o grande problema é que um mesmo atributo pode ou não ser required dependendo de uma regra no banco. Como eu tornaria este atributo dinâmico?

Comment: O EntityFramework não trabalha assim. Ele supõe que todas as regras das propriedades mapeadas em banco estão no Model.